# Get the last instance of data from a list

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and have no idea how to do this.  I have a web page that is displaying data. The user enters some data for a search and then a results page is shown displaying the results of the search.

I want some text at the top showing the search criteria. This is anychart stuff by the way but the javascript concept should be the same.

So in the code below apiInstanceList contains all the search criteria (origin, destination and dates) and the code below would always show the search criteria of the first search!

So the first search will be in ${apiInstanceList[0], a second search would be in ${apiInstanceList[1], etc. What I want to do is always show the LATEST data, whether it be the first search or the "nth" search. Not sure how to do this in Javascript!

```
  myChart.title('Results for flight from ' + "${apiInstanceList[0].origin}" + ' to ' + "${apiInstanceList[0].destination}" + ' from ' + "${apiInstanceList[0].departureDate}" + ' to ' + "${apiInstanceList[0].returnDate}");
```

How do I always show the search criteria from the latest search? Any help appreciated. Javascript noob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
apiInstanceList[apiInstanceList.length - 1]
```

Or to be more specific:

```
var lastPoint = apiInstanceList[apiInstanceList.length - 1];
myChart.title('Results for flight from ' + lastPoint.origin + ' to ' + lastPoint.destination + ' from ' + lastPoint.departureDate + ' to ' + lastPoint.returnDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do: 
`apiInstanceList.slice(-1)[0]`